# Why does this execute a jump instruction?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

I have just seen a very interesting C code in the boot loader of a small embedded product.

The code consists of two parts: boot loader and the main code. The start of the main code address is stored in a function pointer. Below is the code I'm talking about

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t myOtherField;
  void (*mainCodeStartAddress)(void);
} MyStruct;

MyStruct myStruct = {0x89ABCDEF, 0x12345678};

void main(void) {
  // Some code
  ...
  myStruct.mainCodeStartAddress(); // Jump to the start of the application
}
```

I can't figure out why this works? Why does a machine go to the application code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Memory is memory, code is data.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Great hint. I wish I knew what it meant :D

Comment: @RobertHarvey I still don't get it. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @RobertHarvey is saying that the function pointer is really just an address to the start of the function block in the end. i.e: a memory address. By passing the address in directly, you really are just saying 'treat the contiguous block of memory at the address as a function and execute it'

Comment: What I haven't quite figured out yet is what goes into myOtherField.  It's probably a JMP instruction with a memory address.  But it will look just like a number here (or a series of bytes, if you will), just as it does to the processor if you point the Program Counter at it.  That's what I meant by "data is code."

Comment: @RobertHarvey If we knew the architecture this compiling on, it would be trivial to figure it out. Since we don't, we can only guess.

Comment: @VaughanHilts: Exactly.

Comment: @VaughanHilts I changed my struct. Turns out I place myOtherField into an incorrect location.

Comment: That actually makes more sense.  Assuming suitable code exists at `*mainCodeStartAddress`, the `struct` merely serves as a dereferencing mechanism, allowing you to write `myStruct.mainCodeStartAddress();` and have the C compiler compile machine code that executes the JMP to that address for you.  `myOtherField` is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think 0x9ABCDEFG is a valid hexadecimal constent.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Why the vague hint?  This is a Q&A site; it seems that you might usefully post an answer.

Comment: @Clifford: While I understand C pretty well, I don't code in it on a regular basis, and the language lawyer pedants will attack whatever answer I provide.

Comment: It is not helpful that you say *"Below is the code I'm talking about"* when in fact this is quite evidently not *real* code.  You should make that clear or preferably post real code. The probably irrelevant `myOtherField` appears to have no role in this question.

Comment: @Clifford `myOtherField` is probably there as a placeholder to indicate that `void (*mainCodeStartAddress)(void);` is not the only member in the `struct`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I think you are too hard on yourself; but a good answer does not necessarily call for code in this case anyway.  The more helpful citizens would just fix your code in any case without fuss or ridicule - the question is not about syntax after all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey :  I appreciate that, but it is a distraction that has attracted comment, so probably best omitted.  Even the struct itself is not necessary to the technique, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Clifford Can't post real code for copyright reasons. Robert Harvey is right  `myOtherField` is a placeholder to indicate that `void (*mainCodeStartAddress)(void);` is not the only member in the `struct`.

Comment: @flashburn : That does not change the fact that you should make that clear in the question.  Besides that, using an illustrative fragment of *actual* code almost certainly counts as [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use).   It is probably better to elide (use ellipsis) rather than include irrelevant code.

Answer (score 6):

The construct `void (*mainCodeStartAddress)(void)` declares a function pointer named `mainCodeStartAddress`. It will point to a function taking no arguments and that doesn't return anything.

You can assign any function of the same type to a function pointer, for example:

```
void some_function(void)
{
    // Do something useful
}

mystruct.mainCodeStartAddress = some_function;
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
mystruct.mainCodeStartAddress();  // Same as calling some_function();
```

In your example a fixed address is assigned to the function pointer, so when you call the function it points to it jumps to that address and executes it.

Answer (score 1):

If the application code is built with a start address of `0x12345678` (an unlikely address that I assume you have made up for illustration?), then the bootloader need only jump to that start address to start the application.  This can be achieved in C code by setting a function-pointer specifically to that address to that *a priori* known start address value and issuing a call via that function-pointer.  A pointer of any kind is merely a memory address, a function pointer is the address of some code, and a call to a void function is simple a call to some address.

Whether this is implemented by a jump, call, or branch instruction is architecture and instruction set dependent; but that does not matter in this case.  Neither does it matter that the start address is not a "function" as such, since this function will never return - the separately compiled and linked application code will run it's own C runtime start-up and establish a new stack and static initialisation, destroying the runtime environment of the bootloader.  All that is required is that the processor's program-counter is set to the specific address, and that is achieved by calling the function via a pointer.  It could equally be achieved for example by:

```
typedef void(*tStartAddress)(void);
((tStartAddress)(0x12345678)() ; // Set PC to start address
```